How to debug a noisy oscilloscope
I've had an inexpensive handheld integrated digital oscilloscope for close to a year, and used it well on various projects.  It's been on the shelf for 6 months, and the signal I get now is very noisy, to the point of limited usefulness.
I first assumed that this must be do to my error.  However, even when I connect the probes to its own AWG on a simple 1 MHz sine wave, I get the noise, which makes me conclude that the scope (or probes) has somehow broken.  (This is plausible, because, at the least, the components are of poor mechanical quality: the compensation screws on the probes broke almost immediately after first use, and one of the alligator clips broke off almost immediately as well.)
I don't believe the noise is due to poor compensation.  Even though the scope isn't compensated well, that should create a distorted but constant signal.  What I'm seeing is a noisy signal that keeps on jumping around and fluctuating, making it hard to read.
Further information:

The noise occurs on both channels and both probes, but not necessarily to the same degree
The noise seems to be affected by how I hold the probes
I didn't clip the AWG cable directly to the probe, but instead used a small jumper wire beneath them, and another small jumper wire between their grounds

Question: Is it possible for a scope or probes to just break while sitting on in their box (perhaps getting moved around, not necessarily gently)? Is this the most likely explanation?
Since the components of the scope are basically ICs, should I assume its the probes that need to be replaced? Amazon sells probes from $10s to $100s.  Will the cheaper ones likely have the same problems? (I'm hesitant to shell out more for expensive probes, especially when I have a cheaper scope.)
Is there another potential cause?
My next step up would be a PC based integrated system such as Digilent Analog Discovery. But I'm skeptical if that will provide any better results.  It's gotten good reviews, but I imagine under the hood, the components and therefore reliability are no different than the integrated Chinese handheld scopes.  Is that a concern?
I don't currently have the space (or budget) to upgrade to name brands (I need a scope and a function generator).

Update (to answer questions of comments)
The probes are 10x.  The scope is a Hantek 2D42 purchased on Amazon.  I'm considering buying new probes, but am not sure if that will help, or replacing it with an Analog Discovery 3, but not sure if that will be any more reliable.

Is it possible from cheap crap electronics from China to spontaneously break or self-combust? Yes. You can't buy stuff like this from Amazon or other similar junk dealers and expect any form of quality in return.

jumping around (vertically or horizontally?) may indicate a sync problem, which may have a common cause with fluctuating: GND connection problem (swirl around the clip some). (Given tight budget, I assume no differential probe.) (Operate any mechanical switches involved some.)

Suggest a process of elimination.  Swap out the suspect probes for other probes, or just co-ax cable connected to a sig-gen, or even a BNC terminator.  If the problem remains then its the scope; if the problem goes away then its the probes.  You can make your own probes, several youtube videos show how, cost depends on what bandwidth you need.

Take a picture of this 'noise' and post it, the word noise can cover many different types, with different causes, and so different fixes. Short the inputs directly at the scope front panel. Is there still noise?

Is the battery fully charged?

Failure after sitting on a shelf suggests the possibility of electrolytic capacitors gone bad. They may reform/heal if you leave the scope on for 2-6 hours. (Or not).

Come on, it's a f-in' $200 scope. It is quite possible that no components or probes are faulty. It could just be bad design, made bad on purpose, for the explicit purpose of scamming people.
